# How can I connect Qcombobox with pyqt5 created keyboard in python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I hope everyone is well. I need your help I want to connect the pyqt5 created keyboard with the combo box. Qcombobox works fine with the pc keyboard .but when I pass the text with pyqt5 created keyboard it will not give any response.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))


    # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)






class KeyboardWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(KeyboardWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.currentTextBox = None

        self.signalMapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.signalMapper.mapped[int].connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QGridLayout()

        # p = self.palette()
        # p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(),Qt.white)
        # self.setPalette(p)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.combo_box = ExtendedComboBox()
        #self.combo_box.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        string_list = ['hola muchachos', 'adios amigos', 'hello world', 'good bye']
        self.combo_box.addItems(string_list)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box, 0, 0, 1, 13)

        names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                 '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '(', ')']

        positions = [(i + 1, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(13)]

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):

            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
            button.setFixedHeight(25)
            button.setFixedWidth(25)

            button.KEY_CHAR = ord(name)
            button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(button, button.KEY_CHAR)
            layout.addWidget(button, *position)

        # Cancel button
        cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
        cancel_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        cancel_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        cancel_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Cancel
        layout.addWidget(cancel_button, 5, 0, 1, 2)
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(cancel_button, cancel_button.KEY_CHAR)
        cancel_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Cancel button
        clear_button = QPushButton('Clear')
        clear_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        clear_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        clear_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Clear
        layout.addWidget(clear_button, 5, 2, 1, 2)
        clear_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(clear_button, clear_button.KEY_CHAR)
        clear_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Space button
        space_button = QPushButton('Space')
        space_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        space_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        space_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Space
        layout.addWidget(space_button, 5, 4, 1, 3)
        space_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(space_button, space_button.KEY_CHAR)
        space_button.setFixedWidth(85)

        # Back button
        back_button = QPushButton('Back')
        back_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        back_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        back_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Backspace
        layout.addWidget(back_button, 5, 7, 1, 2)
        back_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(back_button, back_button.KEY_CHAR)
        back_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Enter button
        enter_button = QPushButton('Enter')
        enter_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        enter_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        enter_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Enter
        layout.addWidget(enter_button, 5, 9, 1, 2)
        enter_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(enter_button, enter_button.KEY_CHAR)
        enter_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Done button
        done_button = QPushButton('Done')
        done_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        done_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        done_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Home
        layout.addWidget(done_button, 5, 11, 1, 2)
        done_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(done_button, done_button.KEY_CHAR)
        done_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 300)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def buttonClicked(self, char_ord):

        txt = self.combo_box.currentText()
        print(txt)

        if char_ord == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            txt = txt[:-1]
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Enter:
            txt += chr(10)
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Home:
            self.currentTextBox.setText(txt)
            self.text_box.setText("")
            self.hide()
            return
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Clear:
            txt = ""
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Space:
            txt += ' '
        else:
            txt += chr(char_ord)
        self.combo_box.setCurrentText(txt)


class KeyboardUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #first_name = VKQLineEdit(name='First Name', mainWindowObj=self)
        #last_name = VKQLineEdit(name='Last Name', mainWindowObj=self)

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        #layout.addWidget(first_name, 0, 0)
        #layout.addWidget(last_name, 1, 0)

        self.keyboardWidget = KeyboardWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.keyboardWidget, 0, 0, 10, 10)
        mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.keyboardWidget.show()

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 320)
        self.setWindowTitle('StethoX v1.0')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = KeyboardUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you clarify what is the expected behavior? Do you expect the popup to open when text is typed with the virtual keyboard?

Comment: yes .expecting same behavior as on PC keyBoard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are filling the text field with programmatically the cursor is not present which is responsible for dropdown menu of qcombobox. So you need to create another functionality to do so.
I would suggest just create a qlistwidget just below the qcombobox and make it appear like the qcombobox dropdown menu.
Connect the QComboBox textchanged event with QListWidget items display and then you can be able to create your functionality.

Otherwise there is another way to do this. You can just setFocus of qcombobox and type the charaters with the help of pyautogui.
I already edited your code you can test it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSortFilterProxyModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyautogui as ui
class ExtendedComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setEditable(True)

        # add a filter model to filter matching items
        self.pFilterModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(self.model())

        # add a completer, which uses the filter model
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.pFilterModel, self)
        # always show all (filtered) completions
        self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)

        # connect signals
        self.lineEdit().textEdited.connect(self.pFilterModel.setFilterFixedString)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)


    # on selection of an item from the completer, select the corresponding item from combobox
    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        if text:
            index = self.findText(text)
            self.setCurrentIndex(index)
            self.activated[str].emit(self.itemText(index))


    # on model change, update the models of the filter and completer as well
    def setModel(self, model):
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModel(model)
        self.pFilterModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.completer.setModel(self.pFilterModel)


    # on model column change, update the model column of the filter and completer as well
    def setModelColumn(self, column):
        self.completer.setCompletionColumn(column)
        self.pFilterModel.setFilterKeyColumn(column)
        super(ExtendedComboBox, self).setModelColumn(column)






class KeyboardWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(KeyboardWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.currentTextBox = None

        self.signalMapper = QSignalMapper(self)
        self.signalMapper.mapped[int].connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QGridLayout()

        # p = self.palette()
        # p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(),Qt.white)
        # self.setPalette(p)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.combo_box = ExtendedComboBox()
        #self.combo_box.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        string_list = ['hola muchachos', 'adios amigos', 'hello world', 'good bye']
        self.combo_box.addItems(string_list)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box, 0, 0, 1, 13)

        names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                 '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '(', ')']

        positions = [(i + 1, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(13)]

        for position, name in zip(positions, names):

            if name == '':
                continue
            button = QPushButton(name)
            button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
            button.setFixedHeight(25)
            button.setFixedWidth(25)

            button.KEY_CHAR = ord(name)
            button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(button, button.KEY_CHAR)
            layout.addWidget(button, *position)

        # Cancel button
        cancel_button = QPushButton('Cancel')
        cancel_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        cancel_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        cancel_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Cancel
        layout.addWidget(cancel_button, 5, 0, 1, 2)
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(cancel_button, cancel_button.KEY_CHAR)
        cancel_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Cancel button
        clear_button = QPushButton('Clear')
        clear_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        clear_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        clear_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Clear
        layout.addWidget(clear_button, 5, 2, 1, 2)
        clear_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(clear_button, clear_button.KEY_CHAR)
        clear_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Space button
        space_button = QPushButton('Space')
        space_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        space_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        space_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Space
        layout.addWidget(space_button, 5, 4, 1, 3)
        space_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(space_button, space_button.KEY_CHAR)
        space_button.setFixedWidth(85)

        # Back button
        back_button = QPushButton('Back')
        back_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        back_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        back_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Backspace
        layout.addWidget(back_button, 5, 7, 1, 2)
        back_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(back_button, back_button.KEY_CHAR)
        back_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Enter button
        enter_button = QPushButton('Enter')
        enter_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        enter_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        enter_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Enter
        layout.addWidget(enter_button, 5, 9, 1, 2)
        enter_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(enter_button, enter_button.KEY_CHAR)
        enter_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        # Done button
        done_button = QPushButton('Done')
        done_button.setFixedHeight(25)
        done_button.setFont(QFont('Arial', 12))
        done_button.KEY_CHAR = Qt.Key_Home
        layout.addWidget(done_button, 5, 11, 1, 2)
        done_button.clicked.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
        self.signalMapper.setMapping(done_button, done_button.KEY_CHAR)
        done_button.setFixedWidth(60)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 300)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def buttonClicked(self, char_ord):

        txt = self.combo_box.currentText()
        print(txt)

        if char_ord == Qt.Key_Backspace:
            txt = txt[:-1]
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Enter:
            txt += chr(10)
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Home:
            self.currentTextBox.setText(txt)
            self.text_box.setText("")
            self.hide()
            return
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Clear:
            txt = ""
        elif char_ord == Qt.Key_Space:
            txt += ' '
        else:
            txt += chr(char_ord)
        self.combo_box.setFocus(True)
        ui.write(txt)
#         self.combo_box.setCurrentText(txt)


class KeyboardUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #first_name = VKQLineEdit(name='First Name', mainWindowObj=self)
        #last_name = VKQLineEdit(name='Last Name', mainWindowObj=self)

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        #layout.addWidget(first_name, 0, 0)
        #layout.addWidget(last_name, 1, 0)

        self.keyboardWidget = KeyboardWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.keyboardWidget, 0, 0, 10, 10)
        mainWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.keyboardWidget.show()

        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 320)
        self.setWindowTitle('StethoX v1.0')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = KeyboardUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```